# Does boost asio strand run all handlers on the same thread?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

The boost asio documentation talks about executors but I can't see if that implies the same thread.
The reason I'm curious about this is that the purpose of a strand seems to be to allow the developer not to have to worry about multithreading issues.  If that is the case then I see two options for a strand, assuming more than one thread in the io_service/context:

1. Run all handlers on the same *thread* for the lifetime of the strand
2. Use different threads but

   1. Use some mechanism to make sure one handler runs after the other
   2. If run on a different thread make sure you use a memory fence so the second handler sees all updates from the previous handler

(I strongly suspect it is impossible to do 2.1 without doing 2.2)

The problem with 2. is that it hits performance because it requires fences, but I don't see anywhere that explicitly says a strand always uses the same *thread*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

All that is guaranteed is that

- all handlers are invoked on a thread that is invoking `run[_one]` or `poll_[one]` on the execution context. This is is true for handlers on any executor
- strand executors add the guarantee that handlers are only invoked sequentially (non-concurrently) *and* in the order they were posted (see e.g. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context__strand.html#boost_asio.reference.io_context__strand.order_of_handler_invocation)

So yes, depending on situation there may be overhead. However, in some situations there may be optimizations (e.g. `dispatch` from the local strand, or running on a context with a [concurrency hint](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/concurrency_hint.html)).