# How can I assign task to specific thread in a boost::asio::threadpool

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, threadpool, boost-asio

I have some task class like

```
struct Task {

// some members
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    
    void run1();
    void run2();
};

std::vector<Task> tasks(100000);
```

Now I create a threadpool with 10 thread, and I always want to assign my tasks to the same thread in the threadpool. How can I do that? And by the way, if possible, are they serial tasks?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to specify which pool thread executes a given task? That seems contrary to the idea of a "pool."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot. As the commenter says, that runs contrary to the purpose of a thread pool.

If you need to serialize handlers you can use a strand executor. That way you get the guarantee that handlers are executed sequentially, though not necessarily on the same thread.

> *side note: strands are an important Asio concept and are also what libraries use to offer composed async operations, where any intermediate handlers need to be on the same strand as the final completion handler. For that reason, intermediate handlers are all required to use the final handler’s associated executor.*

Some optimizations are in place to make it more likely that handlers posted from the same thread may run immediately in the same thread.

I’ve analyzed/demonstrated some of the implications before:

- [Does boost asio strand run all handlers on the same thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73946197/does-boost-asio-strand-run-all-handlers-on-the-same-thread/73947962#73947962)
- [Boost::asio::strand merges multiple handlers into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71019704/boostasiostrand-merges-multiple-handlers-into-one/71025924#71025924)